# How can I extend TWA application with In-App review?

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity, twa

i create my TWA app based on this repo: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa

I would like to extend the code with In-App Review https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review

Is it possible to do this? I am front-end developer. I have no knowledge of android application

Maybe i can listen to url change? For example in html create anhor

```html
<a href="/#openReviewForm">Rate app now!</a>
```

and app listen and check current hash in location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, I'd recommend using [`@bubblewrap/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bubblewrap/cli) to bootstrap the Trusted Web Activity project, as [svgomg-twa](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa) has been deprecated and replaced by Bubblewrap.

In short, yes, it is possible to integrate [in-app-reviews](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) in a Trusted Web Activity.

The general approach is to use a custom schema, like `my-app://` that is handled by an Android Activity. This Activity will, in turn, launch the review flow and then finish itself.

There are some caveats though:

- You'll need to check if the all is in "trusted web activity mode" in order to display the link, as it only works when inside a Trusted Web Activity.
- This may also not be compatible with Chrome OS, so if you are also deploying the Trusted Web Activity there, I wouldn't recommend integrating in-app reviews.

Here's a [blogpost](https://bandarra.me/2021/01/18/Integrating-in-app-reviews-with-Trusted-Web-Activity/) with more details on how to do it.